# Excel VBA: Using FIND: How to select the cell where the item is found?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to search for a string e.g. "CCC" in an Excel worksheet.
I used the simple code shown.

However, I want VBA to select the cell where the first occurrence of "CCC" is found. (Just like when you do a FIND manually).

How can I modify my code to achieve this?`

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="CCC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("found")
Else
    MsgBox ("not found")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A1").select
Cells.Find(What:="CCC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).activate

activcecell.select
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("found")
Else
    MsgBox ("not found")
End If

End Sub
```

Using activecell.select will select your first find cell.

Comment: You would need to select the result of the `Find` before it would become the `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Hi, Digvjay. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately if I put .activate in line 3, there is a run time error: "Object required". Regards, leon

Comment: yes it was, now it will work fine. It selects the first cell which matches the criteria

Comment: You won't need the `activcecell.select` (which includes a typo) now that you have used `Activate` on the result of the Find.  And you will need to remove the test on whether the `Find` found anything or not as you have not stored the result into the `rng` variable.  And you will need to include some other error handling to cover the situation where the `Find` does not find anything.

Comment: Hi Digvijay. It works now! Thanks to you all, I've found many different methods of doing the same thing! CLOSING!

Answer (score 3):

To select a cell, you can use the `Select` method.  So, if you have a `Range` object which has been set to the cell you want, you can apply the `Select` method to that object, i.e.

```
rng.Select
```

Incorporated into your existing code, it might look something like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="CCC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "found"
        rng.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, in a previous discussion with @ShaiRado, we decided to "in-the-general-case" switch from the 2-phase activation to the single phase `Goto`. Well in fact, "I" decided for both of us :-P, hope you join ;)

Comment: @A.S.H - I will try to remember.  (I so rarely answer questions that require a cell to actually be selected that I will probably forget before the next time it becomes useful.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rng.Select` but it needs the worksheet to be active on top (or you habe to activate it first i.e. rng.Parent.Activate). Simplest is to use `Application.Goto rng`

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Application.Goto rng
    MsgBox ("found")
Else
    MsgBox ("Not found")
End If
```

Comment: someone started switching to `Application.Goto rng` ;)

Comment: The OP's code requires the worksheet to be active anyway, i.e. `Cells.Find`, `After:=ActiveCell`.

Comment: @YowE3K yes, that makes your answer perfectly valid. No objection ;)